# In R, How to provide different shape and fill to the point, showing the legend for fill in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, shapes, fill

For example, I have a data like below,

```
population=rep(c("High", "Low"), time=5)
year=rep(c("2020_H","2020_L","2020_O","2021_L","2021_O"), each=2)
x=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
y=c(15,25,35,45,55,75,100,120,125,145)

dataA=data.frame(population,year,x,y)

   population year    x   y
1        High 2020_H  10  15
2         Low 2020_H  20  25
3        High 2020_L  30  35
4         Low 2020_L  40  45
5        High 2020_O  50  55
6         Low 2020_O  60  75
7        High 2021_L  70 100
8         Low 2021_L  80 120
9        High 2021_O  90 125
10        Low 2021_O 100 145

ggplot(data=dataA, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  stat_smooth(method='lm', linetype=1, se=FALSE, formula=y~x, linewidth=0.5, 
              color="dark red") +
  geom_point(aes(fill=year, shape=population), color="black", size=4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values= c("Dark red","Dark blue", "Orange", "purple", "dark green"))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,24))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,100,20),limits=c(0,100))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,150,50),limits=c(0,150))+
  guides(shape="none") +
  theme_classic(base_size=16, base_family="serif")+
  theme(legend.position=c(0.8, 0.2),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.key=element_rect(color=alpha("grey",.05), fill=alpha("grey",.05)),
        legend.background= element_rect(fill=alpha("grey",.05)),
        axis.line=element_line(linewidth=0.5, colour="black"))+
windows(width=5.5, height=5)
```

and I generated one graph. I provided different shape to population, and different color to year. Then, I hide a legend for shape using `guides(shape="none")`. However, the legend for fill does not provide correct color index. I'd like to show the different color in the legend for year.

Could you tell me how to do it?

Always many thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the default shape used for `geom_point` has no `fill` aes. And as this shape is also used as `key_glyph` in the `fill` legend you end up with black points. To fix that switch the `shape` used for the legend to one which supports fill, i.e. `shape=21`, using the `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = dataA, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  stat_smooth(
    method = "lm", linetype = 1, se = FALSE, formula = y ~ x, linewidth = 0.5,
    color = "dark red"
  ) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = year, shape = population), color = "black", size = 4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Dark red", "Dark blue", "Orange", "purple", "dark green")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 20), limits = c(0, 100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 150, 50), limits = c(0, 150)) +
  guides(shape = "none", fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21))) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16, base_family = "serif") +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(0.8, 0.2),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.key = element_rect(color = alpha("grey", .05), fill = alpha("grey", .05)),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = alpha("grey", .05)),
    axis.line = element_line(linewidth = 0.5, colour = "black")
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine `population` and `year` for mapping.
When you want to merge legends, the mapping variables **should be identical**.

After merging the two categorical variables, all you need to do is mapping the combined variable (`group`) to `shape` and `color`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
dataA <- data.frame(
  population=rep(c("High", "Low"), time=5),
  year=rep(c("2020_H","2020_L","2020_O","2021_L","2021_O"), each=2),
  x=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100),
  y=c(15,25,35,45,55,75,100,120,125,145)
  
)
dataA$group <- paste(dataA$year,dataA$population, sep=" ")

colors <- c("Dark red","Dark blue", "Orange", "purple", "dark green")
shapes <- c(21,24)

ggplot(data=dataA, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  stat_smooth(method='lm', linetype=1, se=FALSE, formula=y~x, linewidth=0.5,
              color="darkred") +
  geom_point(aes(fill=group, shape=group), size=4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values= rep(colors,each=2),
                     labels = dataA$group,
                     name= "Year & Pop.") +
  scale_shape_manual(values= rep(shapes, 5),
                     labels = dataA$group,
                     name= "Year & Pop.") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,100,20),limits=c(0,100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,150,50),limits=c(0,150)) +
  # guides(shape="none") +
  theme_classic(base_size=16, base_family="serif")+
  theme(legend.position=c(0.85, 0.3),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.key=element_rect(color=alpha("grey",.05), fill=alpha("grey",.05)),
        legend.background= element_rect(fill=alpha("grey",.05)),
        axis.line=element_line(linewidth=0.5, colour="black"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>